# Splitting a Comma-Separated String in Scala: Missing Trailing Empty Strings?

Tags: string, scala, split

I have a data file in csv format.
I am trying to split each line using the basic split command `line.split(',')`
But when I get a string like this `"2,,"`, 
instead of returning an array as thus `Array(2,"","")`
I just get an `Array: Array(2)`.
I am most definitely missing something basic, could someone help point out the correct way to split a comma separated string here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is inherited from Java. You can achieve behavior you want by using the `split(String regex, int limit)` overload:

```
"2,,".split(",", -1) // = Array(2, "", "")
```

Note the `String` instead of `Char`.

As explained by the Java Docs, the `limit` parameter is used as follows:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Using `split(separator: Char)` will call the overload above, using a `limit` of zero.

Comment: Thank You LimbSoup, But what's the use of the limit variable?

Comment: Edited my response to include the explanation from the java docs. It's a bit long.