# Splitting strings in scala

Tags: string, scala

I have spotted this "strange" behavior in the scala function `split` of class `string`:

`"a:b::".split(":")` returns `Array[String] = Array(a, b)`

Instead, I would like to get `Array[String] = Array(a, b, "", "")`

Do you have an idea to get such a response?

Comment: You could always do a replaceAll("::",": :")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Split in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273896/string-split-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `limit` parameter with `-1`:

```
scala> "a:b::".split(":", -1)
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, "", "")
```

There is a longer overload with the signature `split(regex: String, limit: Int)`, but you're using the overload with only the `regex` argument, which calls the former overload with a `limit` of zero. When the `limit` is zero, empty strings are discarded from the end of the array.

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> If n [limit] is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, **and trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

Comment: Thamk you for the **detailed** answer :)